# Get date of first Monday of the week?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if you guys know how to get the date of currents week's monday based on todays date?

i.e 2009-11-03 passed in and 2009-11-02 gets returned back

/M

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039/how-can-i-get-the-datetime-for-the-start-of-the-week

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This is what i use (probably not internationalised):

```
DateTime input = //...
int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek;
DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);
```

Comment: Yes, indeed: Not internationalized. Monday is not always the first day of week.

Comment: You can get the first day of week using: CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek

Comment: Actually the first day of the week according to culture is of no interest in this case; the OP wants the monday of the week, not the first day of the week.

Comment: -1. Given a Sunday, this returns the next day, rather than 6 days ago. (`DayOfWeek.Monday` is `1`, `input.DayOfWeek` is `0` for a Sunday.)

Comment: @Rawling: Hence the "not internationalised" in my answer - in the UK, Sunday is the first day of the week, so the following day is the Monday of that week.

Comment: Apologies and don't take it personally, I just wanted to voice a dissenting opinion for people who Google "first day of week" and get this. (Interesting that you give Sunday as fdow for UK, as in the `en-GB` culture it's Monday.)

Comment: @Rawling: It's defiantly something to be aware of - why can't it be the same everywhere? :(

Comment: If the 'input' is 1/1/2017 (a Sunday) this code gives 2/1/2017 (the following Monday and the beginning of a new week!) as the first day of the week?!?!?!?

Comment: var weekStart = input.AddDays(now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? -6 : DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek);

Answer (score 65):

The Pondium answer can search Forward in some case. If you want only Backward search I think it should be:

```
DateTime input = //...
int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek;
if(delta > 0)
    delta -= 7;
DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);
```

Comment: This should be the proper answer as it handles Sundays, i.e. FirstDayOfWeek is Monday, so if Sunday is the input date it should return the Monday before. The accepted answer does not.

Comment: +1 If the 'input' is 1/1/2017 (a Sunday) this code gives 26/12/2016 as the first day of the week! Not 2/1/2017 (which the accepted answer gives!)

Comment: It also works for 01/01/2019 = 31/12/2018!

Comment: var monday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek > 0 ? (DayOfWeek.Monday - DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) - 7 : DayOfWeek.Monday - DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek).Date;

Comment: This is worked for me. Also on sunday or monday. It's just work! Thanks

Comment: Yes, this handles sundays properly!

Answer (score 8):

Something like this would work

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
while(dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday) dt = dt.AddDays(-1);
```

I'm sure there is a nicer way tho :)

Answer (score 6):

```
public static class DateTimeExtension
{
    public static DateTime GetFirstDayOfWeek(this DateTime date)
    {
        var firstDayOfWeek = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

        while (date.DayOfWeek != firstDayOfWeek)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(-1);
        }

        return date;
    }
}
```

International here. I think as extension it can be more useful.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek
```

Why don't use native solution?

Comment: The question is to get the specific date (i.e. 2015-11-20) not which day is defined as the first day.

Answer (score 1):

```
var now = System.DateTime.Now;

var result = now.AddDays(-((now.DayOfWeek - System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek + 7) % 7)).Date;
```

Probably will return you with Monday. Unless you are using a culture where Monday is not the first day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public DateTime FirstDayOfWeek(DateTime date)
{
    var candidateDate=date;
    while(candidateDate.DayOfWeek!=DayOfWeek.Monday) {
        candidateDate=candidateDate.AddDays(-1);
    }
    return candidateDate;
}
```

**EDIT** for completeness: overload for today's date:

```
public DateTime FirstDayOfCurrentWeek()
{
    return FirstDayOfWeek(DateTime.Today);
}
```

Comment: Why looping??, there are ways to-do it without a loop. See answers below.