# How do I get date from week, working also with 53-week years? c#

Tags: c#, datetime, date, week-number

I have made a function to cound the weeks in a year, and that works fine. The problem is that I need a method to get the mondaydate of the week. This is a swedish calendar.

The code below works well for years that have 52 weeks, but some years(like 2009) has 53 weeks. Then I got a date from januari as the mondaydate(cant be right). So please help me to get it to work for all years.

What I probably could do is check if the year has 53 weeks and then do some checks but I'd like it to go smooth without special checks.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
    public static DateTime GetDateFromWeek(int year, int week)
    {
        //First day of the year
        DateTime d = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.MiddleEastFrench);
        d = calendar.AddWeeks(d, week);
        d = d.AddDays(1 - (double)d.DayOfWeek);
        return d;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that 2009 has 53 weeks!

Comment: I'll check all answers in a second! :)

Comment: I think I have an answer that works for all cultures.  I had problems with all the other solutions proposed  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553878/how-to-do-i-invert-the-week-returned-from-calendar-getweekofyear-back-to-a-datet/16553879#16553879

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your base problem is the assumption that `DateTime d = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);` is in the first week of the year, but it could belong to week 52/53 of the previous year.

You will find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662379/calculate-date-from-week-number/662547#662547).

Comment: Thanks. Nice that you pointed out to me what I was doing wrong aswell :)

Comment: BTW some pointers on the code. Why use Debug.Assert(>= 1) and not throw an exception? In my opinion that would be a good place for an argument exception

Comment: @Oskar: Assert does throw an exception. But you're right, in production code I would throw a 'normal' exception.

Comment: Exactly because if you compile for release then all Debug.Assert will go away. :/

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
public static DateTime GetDateFromWeek(int year, int week)
{
    GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.MiddleEastFrench);
    DateTime d = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
    int weeksInYear = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
    int weeksToSubtract = weeksInYear - week;
    d = calendar.AddWeeks(d, -weeksToSubtract);
    d = d.AddDays(1 - (int)d.DayOfWeek);
    return d;
}
```

Comment: This works well but I like that Henk Holterman's solution is a bit more generic. +1 tho for providing a solution

Comment: Both solutions do more or less the same, except mine started at the end of the year instead of at the beginning. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Yeah, made some unit tests and they returned the same so. He was a bit faster than you aswell ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the following question, I think it is what you are asking:

[Get date of first Monday of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665832/get-date-of-first-day-of-week)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (cmb_mode_of_service.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Weekly Service")
            {
                int year = 0;
                if (cmb_term_of_service.SelectedItem.ToString() == "One Year")
                {
                    year = 1;
                }

                if (cmb_term_of_service.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Two Year")
                {
                    year = 2;
                }

                if (cmb_term_of_service.SelectedItem.ToString() == "three year")
                {
                    year = 3;
                }

                DateTime currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(service_start_date.Text);
                DateTime Enddate = currentdate.AddYears(+year);


                char c1 = 'A';
                int c2 = 1;
                for (var dt1 = currentdate; dt1 <= Enddate; dt1 = dt1.AddDays(7))
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["SN"] = c2++;
                    dr["serviceid"] = "S4-" + c1++;
                    dr["servicedate"] = dt1.ToString();
                    dr["servicestatus"] = "Pending";
                    dr["serviceexcutive"] = "Not Alowed";
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                }
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

            }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?