# Retrieve date of the prior Tuesday

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to retrieve the date, month, and year of the last Tuesday relative to any given date. For example, today is Friday, 1st March 2013. I want my method to return the date of the prior Tuesday: 26th February, 2013. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I haven't tried this, as I do not know how to achieve this. My input will be today's date , Datetime.Now, and I require the last tuesday's info as output

Comment: So google is not working, then for a start point you may read [ASP.net get the next tuesday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346119/asp-net-get-the-next-tuesday)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Now;

while(yesterday.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Tuesday) {
  yesterday = yesterday.AddDays(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
var lastTuesday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(
     -1 * (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Tuesday));  
var lastMonday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(
     -1 * (DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday));
```

Answer (score 0):

This was essentially answered here: [Get date of first Monday of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665832/get-date-of-first-day-of-week)

```
DateTime input = DateTime.Now;
int delta = DayOfWeek.Tuesday - input.DayOfWeek;
DateTime tuesday = input.AddDays(delta);
```