# Calculate date with monday as dayofweek=1

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code:

```
public static DateTime calcMondayDate(DateTime input)
{
    int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek;
    DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);

    return monday;
}
```

which works great to calculate monday date if sunday is first day of week. But I want it to calculate so monday is first day of week. because if enter 2009-11-29, 2009-11-30 returns back instead of 2009-11-23.

How can I adjust the code for that?

/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
public static DateTime calcMondayDate(DateTime input) {
    int delta = (DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek - 7) % 7;
    DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);
    return monday;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the previous Monday (or same day if a Monday), then I think this should work:

```
public static DateTime calcMondayDate(DateTime input)
{
    int delta = (7 - (DayOfWeek.Monday - input.DayOfWeek)) % 7;
    return input.AddDays(-delta);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime temp = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 7, 0, 0);
starting=temp.AddDays(-(int) temp.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek );
```

This works for me