# Get date of start day (ex Monday) of a week when having a current date of a random day (ex Friday) in that week

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

For example, my starting day of the week is Monday (2/1/2011), when user input is (4/1/2011) Wednesday, is there any built-in functions that can help me get the starting date of the current week?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039/how-can-i-get-the-datetime-for-the-start-of-the-week

Comment: Click This Link For details.I think it will be solve your problem.
[Click Here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684399/get-the-first-day-and-last-day-of-the-week-of-a-given-date/10685083#10685083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that SQL server's `DATEFIRST` setting fits in with your idea of how weeks are aligned (this probably only matters for Saturdays, Sundays, etc), then a DATEADD/DATEDIFF pair from an arbitrary Monday should give the result you want:

```
select DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,'20110103',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'20110103')
```

Where `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` obviously picks todays date. If you were selecting from a table (`Tab`), with a column called `RandomDate`, then you might do:

```
select DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,'20110103',RandomDate),'20110103') as MondayDate
from Tab
```

But I'm confused by your example, since neither the 2nd of January nor the 1st of February (usual interpretation possibilities for '2/1/2011') is a Monday. The random Monday I selected was `'20110103'` - so if, instead, you needed to find the friday for a particular date, you'd use `'20110107'` in both places where `'20110103'` appears

Comment: sorry i just picked random date

Comment: sorry i don't really understand you solution, today is 08/16/2011 so i tried select DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF(week,'20110816',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'20110816') and it returned me 2011-08-16 00:00:00.000 :(

Comment: Ah, sorry. The bit where you're meant to plug in your own date is where I currently have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. the `'20110103'` bit always stays the same.

Comment: ah I know I understand your solution, but as I mention, I only have the current date and I know that Monday will be the starting day of the week, so date of monday is the thing i want to get :(

Comment: @user552279 - the correct statement to find the Monday from today's date would be: `DATEADD(week,DATEDIFF,week,'20110103','20110816'),'20110103')` - like I said, the `'20110103'` bits always stay the same.

Comment: You need `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 1` for this to work on Sundays and `DATEFIRST` does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function for this,

But you can use:

```
SELECT      DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: This will work since '1900-01-01' is a Monday but you need to use `GETDATE() - 1` to work on Sundays.

Answer (score 1):

```
select getdate() - CAST(getdate()-.5 as int)%7
```

or

```
select cast(getdate() - CAST(getdate()-.5 as int)%7 as date)
```