# Month Calendar display dates for Monday - Sunday

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, monthcalendar

I am creating a small program which will soon develop into a timetable and I am practicing using the C# `MonthCalendar`. So far I have managed to display the date selected onto a text label, however I am looking do achieve something slightly different, which I am struggling with.

I have placed seven labels on a form. When I click on a date, I want all seven labels to be populated with dates that correspond to the specific week on which the selected date is located. Can anyone suggest what I need to do to achieve this.

The problem that i want to resolve:
Lets say I select a date from the calendar. E.g 22/01/1013 so on the labels I want to display all the dates in that week starting from the 21st - 27th Jan 2012

To clarify this further:

This is the interface I have come up with:
[image]

And the code that I have so far:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        label8.Text = dt.ToString();
    }

    private void monthCalendar1_DateSelected(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what part of this are you stuck on?

Comment: I am stuck on the part where I need to display the dates of the whole week

Comment: That's not really specific enough. Do you have trouble figuring out which dates to display? How to associate weekdays to labels?

Comment: did you mean no. of week on that day?

Comment: What you are stuck on is not thinking about a way for the user to enter or change the second date.  And third and forth, etc.  You cannot write code without thinking first.

Comment: Lets say I select a date from the calendar. E.g 22/01/1013 so on the labels I want to display all the dates in that week starting from the 21st - 27th Jan 2012

Comment: @HansPassant :)))))))))))))

Comment: you want to display the 7 days on that week with the selected date :)

Comment: @spajce yes please bro :)

Comment: thats cool.. I will try to ask to our best friend (google) :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answer of [zespri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/284111/zespri) and I got this idea from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38049/1080742).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DateTime t = DateTime.Now; //Your selected date from Calendar
        t -= new TimeSpan((int)t.DayOfWeek, 0, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine("\tstart: " + t.Date.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("\tend: " + t.Date.AddDays(7).ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + new string('-', 25));

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            var d = t.AddDays(i);
            if (d.DayOfWeek >= DayOfWeek.Monday && d.DayOfWeek <= DayOfWeek.Friday) //Range: Monday to Friday
                Console.WriteLine(d.DayOfWeek + " : " + d);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm using winforms

Comment: How do I stop it from showing the time i only want the date

Comment: And I want it to start from Monday

Comment: @Tacit, i updated my answer, all you have to do is to migrate that in winforms :)

Answer (score 2):

First, find out the first day of the week. You can do it similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064/284111). Then starting from this date assign the target text to each label.

You can do the latter in 7 lines of code, one for each label, or you can put your labels in an array, in your form initialization code and iterate through the array. Note, that putting the labels into the array will still require 7 lines. Finally you can use [Form.Controls](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls) or [Form.FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol.aspx) to find all your 7 labels in a loop based on their names.