# How to Get the StartDate based on startDayOfweek and current date in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the DateTime for the start of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039/how-can-i-get-the-datetime-for-the-start-of-the-week)

I need to get start date of a week based on a input date and period start DayOfWeek. The week may start either from sunday or monday or etc.

```
//Ger start date based on a date and startdayofweek
GetStartDate(DateTime date, DayOfWeek periodStartDayOfWeek)
{
 // return startdateof week
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular piece of code you're having trouble with, or are you asking us for a full example?

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
while (date.DayOfWeek != periodStartDayOfWeek)
{
    date = date.AddDays(-1);
}

return date;
```

Comment: While it is possible to do this without using a loop, given how often people **** it up, this is probably the safest solution.