# Selecting an entire Week with two DatePickers

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I have a WPF C# Form and I'm trying to default 2 DatePickers to the current Week,

For example, I have fromDate and toDate, I'd like for fromDate to be the beginning of the week and toDate to be the end of the week.

How would I be able to do this with WPF C# Form

Comment: Why can't you just set the date pickers to the beginning and end of hte week?  What's the problem?

Comment: Please don't call a WPF `Window` a "form". That's an insult to my values and beliefs.

Comment: Other than that, close voting. Post the relevant XAML and code of what you already tried and an explanation of how it doesn't work.

Comment: @roryap My question is how would I go about doing this, I'm using sys:DateTime but it doesn't have such an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking how to choose the start and end days of a week given a single date see: [How can I get the DateTime for the start of the week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039/how-can-i-get-the-datetime-for-the-start-of-the-week)

Using the code in the referenced question you can do

```
DateTime dtStart = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
DateTime dtEnd = dtStart.AddDays(6);
```