# How Can i get DateArray of current Running Week With Month a Day And Month in Asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need on this format:

```
string[] DateArray = new string[7] { "6 Apr", "7 Apr", "8 Apr", "9 Apr", "10 Apr", "11 Apr", "12 Apr" };
```

This is Static, I need this Dyanamic. How??

As if today is Wednesday,12 of August, I need My DateArray like:

```
string[] DateArray = new string[7] { "9 Aug", "10 Aug", "11 Aug", "12 Aug", "13 Aug", "14 Aug", "15 Aug" };
```

I think it is clear Now.

Comment: Explain your needs more clearly , add example

Comment: So you're looking to try and find a timespan... have you done any research?

Comment: [Related - How can I get the DateTime for the start of the week?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38039/1324033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

```
public static void Main()
    {
        DayOfWeek firstWeekDay = DayOfWeek.Monday;
        DateTime input = DateTime.Now;
        int delta = firstWeekDay - input.DayOfWeek;
        DateTime monday = input.AddDays(delta);
        var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(x => monday.AddDays(x).ToString("dd MMM")).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", string.Join(" | ", array));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck in this problem then we can do it simply just provide the day in number to the function like

```
WeekDayName = DateConvert.GetDayOfWeek(d) 

 private static string GetDayOfWeek(int d)
        {
          string str = "";
          switch (d)
          {
            case 1:
              str = "Sunday";
              break;
            case 2:
              str = "Monday";
              break;
            case 3:
              str = "Tuesday";
              break;
            case 4:
              str = "Wednesday";
              break;
            case 5:
              str = "Thursday";
              break;
            case 6:
              str = "Friday";
              break;
            case 7:
              str = "Saturday";
              break;
          }
          return str;
        }
```

Then it will convert.You can modify this for month as well.
Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

```
static string[] GetArray(DateTime dt)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(-3, 7).Select(x => dt.AddDays(x).ToString("d MMM", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)).ToArray();
}
```

This is what you wanted