# Net Core 2 StartOfWeek

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

In Net Framework 4.x I can get the start of week by:

```
dateStart = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
weekStart = dateStart.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

But in Net Core the StartOfWeek function doesn't exist.
Any idea how I can achieve this in Net Core 2?

Thanks

Comment: `StartOfWeek` does not exist in any .Net Framework, are you sure you weren't using a custom extension method?

Comment: Such as like this; https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064/2289430

Comment: DavidG your absolutely right, it's an extension I already have in other project... sorry. I need a coffee.